# fix the position of a webpart 

Tags: web-part, javascript

hey all ... i have a query i.e. How can i fix the position of the webpart on a page? in user personalization scope

fixed position means fixed zone & fixed index (top / buttom). & user can not alter its position **is there any javascript by which i can rearrange the webpart at runmtime?**

Answer (score 1):

For any web part if you click on the menu chevron (top right) and select **Edit Web Part** you'll see the properties for the web part. Expand the **Advanced** section. Under there you can uncheck **Allow Zone Change** and **Allow Editing in Personal View** which should do what you're looking for. This can also be set in the defintion of a custom web part, but it's standard for all web parts.

I don't know of any script to alter it dynamically as you need to actually write to the config database. You might be able to access it using SPServices but it's a lot of work for little payback.

Comment: By javascript, I think he was referring to blocking the click/drag event handlers for the web parts.